# Actualizar un registro que tiene claves foraneas

Tags: sql, update, registro

Tengo un formulario en el que voy a actualizar los datos (**hacer un update**) pero el problema es que para poder actualizar los datos **debo actualizar siempre** un campo -municipio- Que actua como clave foranea en la tabla en la que quiero actualizar los datos.Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para poder actualizar un registro sin tener que actualizar el municipio.
**Quiero hacer un update sin que interfiera la clave foranea.**
Aqui esta mi formulario en donde actualizo los datos

```
                       <form action="update_cliente.php" method="post"   name ="formulario" onsubmit="return (e);" >
                           <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label "> Documento de Identidad: </label><br>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Documento de Identidad" name="documento"  class="col-8 "  value="<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>"> <br> <br>
                           </div>            
                           <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Nombres : </label><br><br>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" name="nombres"  class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['nombres'] ?>" > <br> <br>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4  col-form-label ">Apellidos: </label><br><br>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" name="apellidos"  class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['apellidos'] ?>"> <br> <br>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label "> Telefono : </label><br><br>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Telefono " name="telefono"  class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['telefono'] ?>"> <br> <br>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Correo: </label><br><br>
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Correo" name="correo"  class="col-8 "value="<?php echo $datos['correo'] ?>" ><br> <br>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label "> Dirección: </label><br><br>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección" name="direccion"  class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['direccion'] ?>"  > <br> <br>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label " for="depatamento"> Departamento: </label><br>
                                    <select Class="form-control col-8 rounded" name="depatamento" id="tbl_departamento"  class="col-8">
                                        <option value="" disabled> - Seleccione - </option>
                                        <?php foreach ($filas as $op): //llenar las opciones del primer select ?>
                                                                                            <option value="<?=$op['codigo']?>"> <?=$op['nombre']?> </option>
                                                                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row" >
                                <label class="col-4 col-form-label " for="municipio">Municipio: </label><br>
                                    <select Class="form-control col-8 rounded" name="municipio" id="tbl_municipio"  disabled="" class="col-8">
                                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['municipio'] ?>"><?php echo $datos['municipio'] ?></option>
                                       
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                   <!-- Iniciamos el segmento de codigo javascript -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
             var tbl_municipio = $('#tbl_municipio');

            //Ejecutar accion al cambiar de opcion en el select de las bandas
            $('#tbl_departamento').change(function(){
            var departamento_codigo= $(this).val(); //obtener el id seleccionado

            if(departamento_codigo !== ''){ //verificar haber seleccionado una opcion valida

            /*Inicio de llamada ajax*/
            $.ajax({
              data: { departamento_codigo : departamento_codigo }, //variables o parametros a enviar, formato => nombre_de_variable:contenido
              dataType: 'html', //tipo de datos que esperamos de regreso
              type: 'POST', //mandar variables como post o get
              url: '../includes/traer_municipios.php' //url que recibe las variables
            }).done(function(data){ //metodo que se ejecuta cuando ajax ha completado su ejecucion

              tbl_municipio.html(data); //establecemos el contenido html de discos con la informacion que regresa ajax
              tbl_municipio.prop('disabled', false); //habilitar el select
            });
            /*fin de llamada ajax*/

          }else{ //en caso de seleccionar una opcion no valida
            tbl_municipio.val(''); //seleccionar la opcion "- Seleccione -", osea como reiniciar la opcion del select
            tbl_municipio.prop('disabled', true); //deshabilitar el select
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
                          
                          <div class="form-group inline row justify-content-center">
                           <input type="submit" value="Actualizar cliente" id="boton" class="btn btn-primary col-6 rounded-pill"><br> 
                           </div>
                       </form>
```

Si intento actualizar cualquier otro dato sin actualizar el municipio sale este error

```
Notice: Undefined index: municipio in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_cliente\update_cliente.php on line 12
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventario`.`tbl_cliente`, CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_clientes_tbl_municipio1` FOREIGN KEY (`municipio`) REFERENCES `tblmunicipio` (`codigo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Este es el archivo traer_municipios.php , llamado por el ajax de arriba

```
<?php
require_once ('conexion.php'); //libreria de conexion a la base

$departamento_codigo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'departamento_codigo'); //obtenemos el parametro que viene de ajax

if($departamento_codigo != ''){ //verificamos nuevamente que sea una opcion valida
  
 
  if(!$conexion){
    die("<br/>Sin conexión.");

  }

  /*Obtenemos los discos de la departamento seleccionada*/
  $sql = "select codigo, nombre from tblmunicipio where tbl_departamentos_codigo = ".$departamento_codigo;
  $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
  $filas = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
  mysqli_close($conexion);
}

/* el combo dependiente */
?>
 
     </div>    
     <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
    <?php foreach($filas as $op): //creamos las opciones a partir de los datos obtenidos ?>
    <option value="<?= $op['codigo'] ?>"><?= $op['nombre'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Esta es mi tabla cliente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Esta es mi tabla municipio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero puedan ayudarme !

Comment: Hola, intenta cambiando las propiedades de la relacion fk_tbl_clientes_tbl_municipio1 cambiando a ON CASCADE

Comment: Gracias , pensé en eso pero me arrepentí ya que si no tengo mal entendido el concepto, si se actualiza en la tabla cliente, también se actualiza en la tabla municipio, no es así ?

Comment: si, es asi, como por defecto la relación esta en RESTRICT la cual rechaza toda acción de delete o update te genera un error por que no tiene permitido hacer acción alguna, ademas te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la siguiente pregunta para evitar la inyección sql (tal y como esta tu codigo actualmente esta vulnerable) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php

Comment: Gracias tendré en cuenta tu consejo de la inyección sql, pero volviendo al tema, entonces si hago lo que dices no se afectará ningún registro de la tabla municipio ?

Comment: no, no se verán afectados los registros de municipio

Comment: Es que no esta bien esto.. porque haces update de todos los campos? vos necesitas actualizar el campo municipio?? o sea.. vos estas tratando de actualizar municipio con un valor que no existe en la tabla municipio.. eso es correcto???

Comment: No, yo quiero que actualize todos los campos que el usuario desee, por lo tanto debe permitirme actualizar cualquiera.

Comment: Kevin, hice esta relación pero hay un error cerca de -on cascade - y no se cual puede ser : alter TABLE tbl_cliente ADD CONSTRAINT municipio_cliente FOREIGN KEY (municipio) REFERENCES tblmunicipio(codigo) ON CASCADE

Comment: Kevin, hola, intenté cambiar la relación como dijiste, pero el sistema me detecta la relación anterior a la que hice, y me suelta el mismo error, que puede ser ?

Comment: Hola, que contiene la tabla municipio?, por que en el cliente municipio es un varchar y no un int?, has ejecutado la consulta directamente en tu gestor de bd

Comment: Kevin, si hice la relación directamente en el sql de phpmyadmin, voy a subir la imagen de la estructura de la tabla municipio, por favor verificala .

Comment: mmmm, y si en tu consulta de php agregas el codigo de municipio directamente? quisas hay algun espacio, mmm

Answer (score 0):

- Quita la actualización del campo municipio del **query** de `update`, `update` no necesita actualizar todos los campos,
- Otro, el valor de la llave foránea visualizado es el valor relacionado pero no es valor de real de la tabla municipio ya que ese es un código que se usa como llave, lo dice el error.

Lo que ingresas en el query de `update` seguramente es un nombre pero el valor de ese es en realidad un código en la tabla municipio, para actualizar este tipo de registros foráneos es recomendable hacerlo con una lista desplegable donde esten las opciones restringidas con los valores relacionados.

Comment: Gracias ! pero en mi caso necesito tener la posibilidad de actualizar el municipio, intenté eliminar del update el campo municipio y funciona, sin embargo no es el resultado que debo darle al usuario.

Comment: si, en ese caso, como dije, genera un menu desplegable porque este municipio debe estar en la tabla de municipios, y como tambien dije el dato a ingresar aqui es el codigo del municipio y no su nombre.

Comment: por otro lado, otra solucion que puedo darte es eliminar el campo codigo y asignar llave a nombre porque este igualmente no debe repetirse.

Comment: tambien a modo de recomendacion, siempre es mejor que los campos relacionados tengan el mismo nombre y asi evitar confusiones.

Comment: Hola, actualizé mi código arriba, no encuentro en que lugar de el archivo traer_municipio.php no traigo el código, podrian ayudarme porfavor ? para traer el codigo del municipio en vez del nombre.